# Spotfire - Count the number of wells over time

Tags: spotfire

I am new to spotfire so please bear with me. I have a simple problem i hope. I have a display that has well production vs time. All I need is count the number of active wells as a function of time. The number of wells in month 1 = 95 but as we approach month 60 only 3 wells are active.

The well name = API14
The columns that a plotted are Oil and Months , Line by API14

I have tried

```
UniqueCount([API14]) OVER (Intersect(All([Axis.Line]))) AS [Cumulative Count]
```

This one gave the total unique API14 over time (95 in this example - light blue line) and not the declining well count as a function of time. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UniqueCount([API14]) OVER (Intersect([MONTHS],All([Axis.Line])))
```